# How to open JavaScript link into iframe in parent

Tags: javascript, iframe, dom-events

I am trying to call dynamically created link in JavaScript into iframe. Dynamic links are being created but links are opening in parent window instead of iframe.

```
    <li><a href="#">New Member Name</a>
  <ul>
    <li><script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var d = new Date()

month=(d.getUTCMonth()+1).toString();
if(month.length<2) month = "0" + month;

day=(d.getUTCDate()).toString();
if(day.length<2) day = "0" + day;

hour=(d.getUTCHours()).toString();
if(hour.length<2) hour = "0" + hour;

minute=(d.getUTCMinutes()).toString();
if(minute.length<2) minute = "0" + minute;

for (x=1 ; x<=10 ; x++)
{
    xx = x.toString();  
    if (xx.length<2) xx = "0" + xx;

    h= "http://apps.facebook.com/evonyoffical/facebook.Uprising.php?F=100002319241135&C=878988&SID=NA46&T=" + d.getUTCFullYear() + "." + month + "." + day + "+" + hour + "." + minute + "." + xx + "&SX=0&FEEDID=10001&GUID=220B83CD-91F8-D26A-B411-25BC9BAF1B5E&k=070d6091c63e5a21b5a1e9b829262396"; target="_rightfb"
    document.writeln("<p>"+("Link "+x).link(h)+"</p>");
}
//-->
</script></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Where the iframe div properties are:

```
<div id=facebook><iframe src='javascript:""' name="rightfb"  width:"900" height:"450"></iframe></div>
```

Comment: change the target="_rightfb"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create the link to write to the src of the iframe. The following produces links that load the url into the iframe however when I tried it I got a response that the website will not allow content to be written to a frame for security reasons (maybe because I was just opening the html file from the file system and not through a server).

```
url= "http://apps.facebook.com/evonyoffical/facebook.Uprising.php?F=100002319241135&C=878988&SID=NA46&T=" + d.getUTCFullYear() + "." + month + "." + day + "+" + hour + "." + minute + "." + xx + "&SX=0&FEEDID=10001&GUID=220B83CD-91F8-D26A-B411-25BC9BAF1B5E&k=070d6091c63e5a21b5a1e9b829262396";
html='<p><a onClick="document.getElementById(\'rightfb\').src=\'' + url + '\'" style="color:blue;cursor:pointer">Link' + x + '</a></p>';
document.write(html);
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this, but this is not working either. I have uploaded on a free webspace for you to check [link](http://alliance100.freewebspace.com/index.html)

Comment: I am unable to find the link you need on that page but I have checked my local copy in IE8, Firefox, Chrome and opera. It works on all of them (displays the security warning in IE and Firefox but displays nothing in the other browsers). try changing the URL to one that does not have the security issue. That works fine on all browsers for me.

Comment: Thanks... its woeking now, issue is with the facebook :)